# jQuery Validation this.optional is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I created my own custom validation method which uses the minlength method in turn, however I get this error:

```
this.optional is not a function
```

My code is here:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validAccount", function(value, element, params) {
        var res = true;
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(value[0]))) {
            res = false;
        } else if (!$.validator.methods.minlength(value.split(""), element, params)) {
            res = false;
        }
        return res;
    }, "The inserted account isn't valid");
```

Can anyone help me? I want understand where the problem is.

Note: In the minlength method I use split because without it I also get getLength is not a function.

Comment: I don't believe you can call one method from inside of another method.  Absolutely NONE of the existing methods attempt to do this, and there are quite a few that are similar enough.  Seriously, you're saving almost nothing here... one line of code for another.

Comment: Ok, so I can't use this way to create my own methods, but then I'll have to re-implement every default method in my custom method. :(

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the code I posted, it's the one I used to create the custom method, I can adds how I call it on initializing validation:

`$("#idform").validate(
rules: {
account: {
validAccount: 4
}
});`
where "account" is name and id of the field. There is nothing more.

Comment: Quote: *"but then I'll have to re-implement every default method in my custom method"* ~ Why would you need to do that?! What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Hundreds of thousands of developers/websites use this plugin without having such an issue as yours. Perhaps you have a misunderstanding about how to implement the built-in methods.  Please edit the question to clearly explain why you can't just use the built-in methods, such as `minlength: 4`, as designed.

Comment: The account field shouldn't start for a number, there is no such built-in method. So I should create it. Also, the account field should be at least n characters. I thought about using the existing method for this instead of re-created it, but I see that this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311949/jquery-validation-this-optional-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1#comment87655666_50311949):

> *"The account field shouldn't start for a number, there is no such built-in method. So I should create it. Also, the account field should be at least n characters. I thought about using the existing method for this instead of re-created it, but I see that this is a bad idea."*

Perhaps you didn't know you can apply several rules to the same field at once. You can write a custom rule that says it should not start with a number, and then use it alongside the default `minlength` rule.

```
$("#idform").validate({
    rules: { 
        account: { 
            validAccount: true, // <- custom rule to make sure does not start with number
            minlength: 4        // <- default rule (at least 4 characters entered)
        } 
    }
});
```

You can use as many default and/or custom rules (methods) as you need.  Also, check out [the `additional-methods.js` file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/additional-methods.js) for even more.

Comment: So I have to follow this way. I thought I could do everything in the custom method. Thank for you help.

Comment: @Huntwer, by far this way is simpler!  Not to mention the way it was intended.